# Why does the "use of local variable with automatic storage from containing function" error message exist?

Tags: c++, compilation, gcc

I have a **C++ language/compiler design curiosity question.** I'm using gcc 11.2.0, -std=gnu++17 on Cygwin.

Why is it an error to directly reference local variables in structures? Lambda functions do this all the time, and they are basically no different from structures containing the operator() method. As an example:

```
static inline void
   language_complaint( void )       // Grumble, grumble, grumble
{  printf("\nlanguage_complaint...\n");

   // Given that this compiles and runs...
   int foo= 22;
   printf("foo: %p->%d\n", &foo, foo);
   std::function bar= [=](void) { printf("foo: %p->%d\n", &foo, foo); };
   bar();

#if true // And so does this...
   struct named {
     int const foo;
     named(int foo) : foo(foo) {}   // Use constructor to copy local variable
     void operator()(void) { printf("foo: %p->%d\n", &foo, foo); }
   } one(foo);
   one();
   bar= one;

// ...And even this, which causes wild stores if improperly used... 
   struct name2 {
     int& foo;
     name2(int& foo) : foo(foo) {} // Use constructor to reference local variable
     void operator()(void) { *foo= 42; printf("foo: %p->%d\n", &foo, foo); }
   } two(foo);
   two();
   bar= two; 
   printf("foo: %p->%d\n", &foo, foo);

#else // Why, then, is this disallowed?
   struct {
     int /* const */ bar= foo;      // Error: Can't access local variable with auto storage
//   int const foo= ::foo;          // Error: Can't find ::foo. (Probably irrelevant)
     void operator()(void) { printf("bar: %p->%d\n", &bar, bar); }
   } one;
   one();
#endif
}
```

This was an attempt to demonstrate a use case as part of the problem description. Instead it obfuscates the question. I'm leaving it, though, so that the critical comments below make sense.

The only justification I can think of is this: When copying automatic variables for later use, it **is** easy to step on your own toes, no matter what method you use. I know, my toes are still sore.

But it seems like the language/compiler designers are trying to save you from yourself *but only* where plain structures are concerned, not for lambda functions or constructor initialized structures. Examples:

This compiles because the `int a` is static:

```
static int a= 'a'; // (Implicitly included in following examples)
static inline std::function<void(void)> ok1(void) {
  struct { 
    int b= a; 
    void operator()(void) {
      printf("a: %p->%d, b: %p->%d\n", &a, a, &b, b);
    } 
  } ret;
  return ret;
}
```

This compiles because lambda functions can freely access automatic data:

```
static inline std::function<void(void)> ok2(void) {
  int b= a; // Copy static "a" into automatic (stack) "b" 
  return [b](void) { (void)b; /* ignore b */ }; 
}
```

This **doesn't** compile because it contains an assignment from stack data:

```
static inline std::function<void(void)> ng1(void) {
  int b= a;
  struct { int c= b; void operator()(void) { /* ignore c */ }} ret;
           ^^^^^^^^^ The error-generating statement
  return ret;
}
```

But you **can** access automatic variables using some extra coding:

```
static inline std::function<void(void)> ok3(void) {
  int b= a;
  struct X {
    int c; X(int p) : c(p) {} // Equivalent to c= b; 
    void operator()(void) { /* ignore c */ }
  } ret(b);
  return ret;
}
```

Let's test:

```
static inline void test(void) {
  std::function<void(void)> f= ok1();
  f(); // a: 0x100402010->97, b: 0xffffcbb0->97

  a= 'b';
  f= ok1();
  f(); // a: 0x100402010->98, b: 0xffffcbb0->98

  a= 'c';
  f(); // a: 0x100402010->99, b: 0xffffcbb0->98
}
```

The compiler specifically tests for and disallows automatic variable assignment for no apparent reason. Is there one? **What does the user, compiler, or anyone or anything else gain from this restriction?**

Comment: In your lambda and your struct `named`, it captures the value of `foo` at the time the constructor is executed. In your unnamed version, it needs to know the default value to use for `bar` at compile time when defining the struct.

Comment: It is disallowed because it would require the struct definition to be generated at runtime, which is impossible.

Comment: You shouldn't re-use variable names so much. I count **five** different entities named `foo` in the code sample, and not all of them have the same type. Even if you didn't confuse yourself when writing this question, the similar names are likely to confuse people trying to answer. It would probably be clearer to have four separate code snippets, one for each approach, and within each snippet, use different names for different entities when reasonable. (The capture-by-value within the lambda is the one case I see where using a different name would be inconvenient.)

Comment: @NathanPierson, in the unnamed version, foo is the default value which cannot be referenced due to a compiler restriction. If foo was a module-level static, it could have been referenced as ::foo.

Comment: @molbdnilo, The struct definition can be generated at runtime, and is simply by using a different initialization syntax. The structs named and name1 demonstrate this. (named is essentially functionally identical to the lambda definition, and name1 is functionally identical to a lambda reference rather than copy.)

Comment: @JaMiT, I could have changed the names to protect the innocent, but all the **foo**s refer to the same thing, either by copy or reference. In the `#else` clause, which fails to compile, even though bar is a copy of foo the names had to differ. Using different names would be just as confusing, but in a different way. I'll change the int* to an int&, which might help clarify that all the foos really are the same integer.

Comment: @FNE: But they're *not* "the same integer". They are the same *value*, but some of them are different *objects*. In every case that works, you'll notice that you must *explicitly* pass the object to the constructor, and you *could have* passed a different integer and the code would still work.

Comment: "The struct definition can be generated at runtime" is not how C++ works. In all your working examples, the definition is generated at compile time, and at run time a particular value is passed to the constructor.

Comment: Of course a different value could be passed. Likewise a different value could be assigned. The question is: "What's the point of the error message." The code demonstrates that it doesn't protect or stop anything. Nicol and Nathan are exactly right, the value passed is a runtime value. So, why is the disallowed statement disallowed?

Comment: *"Using different names would be just as confusing"* -- not necessarily. I don't think it would be that confusing to use names like `foo_named` for the member of `named`, `foo_name2` for the member of `name2`, `foo_param` for the constructor parameters, and something similar for the commented-out member of the unnamed `struct`. This would preserve the implication that they all refer to the same value, while differentiating where each lives.

Comment: @NathanPierson, you are correct. I misspoke. Err, mistyped. Err, erred. It's struct initialization that can and pretty much always is (one way or another) done at runtime, not definition. Note that it's the matter of restricted initialization syntax that's my language complaint. The value= static_value syntax is allowed, but the value= automatic_value syntax is not. The question is, why not? What's value added to the language by this restriction?

Comment: @FNE *"The value= static_value syntax is allowed, but the value= automatic_value syntax is not. The question is, why not?"* They are different beasts. The location of a static variable is known at link time; the location of an automatic variable is not known until runtime -- and need not be unique -- as it depends on the call stack. I advise dropping the idea that any of this has anything to do with "save you from yourself"; in fact drop the programmer's perspective altogether. What challenges would a compiler face trying to implement access to an automatic variable outside the constructor?

Comment: Please do not attempt to answer inside your question. If you feel that more information is required than is in the accepted answer, then you may post your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the cases that work specifically involve you passing an expression to a constructor. Even the lambda version requires you to spell out the variables you intend to capture (or to use a default capture). This effectively counts as a way to specify the lambda's constructor (which is why you can't default construct capturing lambdas).

In C++, a local class is basically convenience notation. The local class declaration and the definitions within it are scoped as if it were defined just before the containing function's definition. As such, it has no access to any function-local names, including those of local variables.

Comment: I have to disagree somewhat with this assessment. Note that lambda functions and structs with operator() methods are closely related. As std::function objects, one can be substituted for the other if the signatures match. Then note that the constructors for op() struts have an exact lambda counterpart, albeit compiler generated and hidden. Any struct can access automatic variables using constructor assignment. The question then becomes, why is struct assignment initialization disallowed (but only) for automatic variables? What's the benefit for the user or the compiler?

Comment: @FNE: You can disagree all you like, but it is what it is: local class definitions are not allowed to touch names declared in the functions in which they are defined. The end. You want to equate the use of a name with passing a value to a constructor, but they're not the same because of *where they are*.

Comment: I don't understand the why of this statement. It probably lies near the heart of why auto assignment initialization is disallowed. How is "touching" a class name in a constructor initializer _functionally_ different from "touching" it by assignment (during construction)? If it's not functionally different, what kind of difference is it (besides the syntax)? Why is assignment from a static area allowed? It could just as well require constructor initialization too.

Comment: @FNE: What does "*"touching" a class name in a constructor initializer*" that mean? You seem to be missing the point of where the name of the local variable is. That name is inside the function, where the constructor *gets called*, not in the *definition* of the class. The definition of the class is effectively outside of the function.

Comment: If this comment was because I (stupidly/sloppily) declared some structs static, you are 111% correct. I fixed this and added a little demo. Now that the struct is no longer static, the assignment from a static variable initialization occurs dynamically at runtime rather than once at compile time. Does this get us closer to being on the same page? I agree that function ng1 fails to compile and that's just the way it is. I have yet to see why that's the way it should be or, alternatively, why static variables should get special treatment. I appreciate your tolerant guidance in this.

Comment: @FNE: My answer explains why it is this way. Static variables do not get special treatment. Local structs simply ***do not have access to local variables***. Local structs are a *fiction*; the struct is effectively (in terms of variable scope) declared outside of the function. That's its scope. The local variables do not exist for the struct because it is effectively declared outside of the function.

Comment: Thanks for the sledgehammer tap. As far as the compiler is concerned, "Local structs are a _fiction_ .. [and are] .. declared outside of the function." This is what I was looking for, an inside look for the **why**. One more paradigm shifted.